# Delphi debug - can I show field names, not just values when evaluating?

Tags: debugging, delphi, expression-evaluation

When I evaluate a variable with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, it's fine with a simple variable. But, when I have something more complex:

[image: Delphi Evaluate/Modify dialog]

...is there any way to show the names of the fields corresponding to those values?

Comment: Instead of typing 'MyControl', type 'MyControl,r'.  That is, append a comma and the letter r to your expression.  If you click the Help button on the dialogue, it will also give you other Display Format Specifiers you can use.

Comment: Apart from the ",r" format specifier: Have you tried the "Inspect" button?

Comment: Indeed, I always press Alt+I after having evaluated my expression. That's in my muscle memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the documentation for the [Evaluate/Modify](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Evaluate/Modify) dialog, you can append `,R` to the end of the expression, eg `myControl,R`:

> ### Display Format Specifiers
>
> By default, the debugger displays the result in the format that matches the data type of the expression. For example, Integer values are displayed in decimal format. **To change the display format, type a comma (,) followed by a format specifier after the expression**.
>
> The following table describes the Evaluate/Modify format specifiers:
>
> | Specifier | Types affected | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | ,R | Record | Record/Structure. For Delphi, **shows both field names and values**, such as (X:1;Y:10;Z:5) instead of (1,10,5). |

Comment: Also available in Delphi 7 (2002) and also for Watches (_Ctrl+F5_).

Comment: Actually that's an even more ancient feature. It goes back to at least Delphi 5. I can't check but I think it was already available in the first Delphi version I ever used: Delphi 3

Comment: @remy That helps - a little. Is there any way to structure it? It is just a monolithic wall of text, albeit with field names

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica nope, the inspector does not provide any control over the structure of the text.